# Best practice about Javascript promise return

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to promise and I am wondering which is the best practice with native Promise (NodeJs).

I put some code below to better understand the question:

**Code_A**

```
function foo(condition) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 if(condition){
    resolve('Promise result!');
 } else {
    reject('Promise rejected!');
 }
});
}
```

**Code_B**

```
function foo(condition) {
 return new Promise(() => {
  if(condition){
    return Promise.resolve('Promise result!');
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('Promise rejected!');
 }
});
}
```

Which is the best option in order to return a Promise? There is some best practice rules to follow?

Comment: The latter seems very wrong. Why would you not just put the `if...else` statement directly into `foo`? In other words, if you are not using `resolve` and `reject` passed into the callback, then there is no need for using `new Promise(...)` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is some best practice rules to follow?

Never create a promise if you already have one.

However, did you actually try your second example? It shouldn't work, because `Promise` ignores the (successful) return value of the executor (see the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-constructor)). In other words, the promise will never be resolved or rejected.

Instead, you could write

```
function foo(condition) {
  if(condition){
    return Promise.resolve('Promise result!');
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('Promise rejected!');
  }
}
```

And which one of these to choose depends on your use case. You can only use the example in this answer if you already know the result. But if an asynchronous processes is involved and the result is determined by that process, you will have to use the first form (since you have to "wait" for that process).

Answer (score 2):

Have recently had a lot of trouble with Promises myself.

Your first code is correct, second builds a needless extra Promise resolution.

The thing about Promises is, they will really come of age when the libraries you include in your code start returning them. So, if I use the 'request' library from NPM today, I will have to write code like:

```
function myRequestPromise(url){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        request(url,(err,res,body)=>{
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(body);
        })
    })
}
```

And then you go

```
myRequestPromise(url).then(doSomething).catch(errors);
```

**Note that you are returning your promise from inside the callback really. This wrapper ensures that all the code that calls it can use Promises.** So, expect your 'library/helper' code to be full of such nested callbacks dirtily converted into Promises.

In the future, when the request library author changes it natively to promises, you can use

`request(url).then(doSomething).catch(errors)`

Taking this further, if you plan to use something like RxJS sometime in the future, you need to add another extra layer. But once the libraries you use upgrade themselves to Promises, and later, hopefully to Observables, writing async code will become much easier.

Comment: You do know that there's a request library from the same authors but with promises? https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: No I didn't, I had to do this to the request library in my code - sorry about the bad example in that case  - point being many async libraries are not promises/a+ compliant.

Comment: it's still a nice example ;) I was just telling you that there is already request promise compilant and there's also libraries like bluebird that allows you to promosify some libraries

Comment: While what you wrote is certainly interesting, it doesn't seem to be relevant to the question...

Comment: @Felix - Just read your answer and re-read the question :) I agree, that answers the question better.